# Do .edmx changes in EF 4 auto update the database?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Do .edmx changes in EF 4 auto update the database?

I was changing some foreign key mapping in my .edmx diagram and wanted the same to reflect in the database (sql 2008)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is the case, I've never tested it. But it will work the other way around, which I think is probably easier to manipulate. So once you make your changes in the database, you can right click on the .edmx diagram and click refresh diagram or something and it will take you through the wizard to updated the diagram to reflect the current state of the Database

Comment: Thanks for your response, just wondering if any one has ever tried this? or can point me to a valid resource for me to check..